# What is the best database table design for point to point distances being stored in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, database-design, azure-sql-database

I intend to store a list of distances from all points to each other.

So if I had only 3 points (A-C) it would be like

```
 | FROM | TO | DISTANCE
 | A    | B  | 10 miles
 | A    | C  | 15 miles
 | B    | C  | 12 miles
```

Obviously you can infer that B to A = 10 miles since you know A to B = 10 miles. In terms of my queries I may be searching for A to B or B to A - I can't guarantee the order of the start and end point of the journey.

I have 1600 points which makes (1600^2 - 1600)/2 = 1.3m possible journeys. What is the best way to store that data for querying by either A to B or B to A?

- Should I duplicate the rows for the reverse journeys leading to 2.5m
  rows and query on that?
- Or should I make a composite clustered index
  on the two columns and search for both the A to B OR the B to A
  knowing at least one exists?
- Or something else clever

This is on SQL Azure in case that makes a difference

Comment: If there is a one-way road between A and B, the distance from A to B may not be the distance from B to A.

Comment: What is your goal? Storage space? Development speed?

Comment: Do you have coordinates for all your points, or just distances?  Also, are these straight-line (calculable) distances, or actual travel distances?

Comment: Oh the bloody Stackoverflow police! What is wrong with you people - I have a problem and would like an opinion on best approach! I have contributed so much with stackoverflow but am finding it so hard to use it when I have a question of late, you get the auto message that this could be open ended and you use your sliver of power to go out of your way to be unhelpful. You people ruin this place!

Answer (score 0):

One other possible way of doing this,

Create an extra column, named 'From_To' as below

```
| FROM | TO | FROM_TO | DISTANCE
| A    | B  | ABA     | 10 miles
| A    | C  | ACA     | 15 miles
| B    | C  | BCB     | 12 miles
```

Now let say if you want to search for distance from `A->B` then your query would be,

```
Select Distance from Distance_Table where From_TO like '%AB%'
```

and for distance from `B->A` you query would be,

```
Select Distance from Distance_Table where From_TO like '%BA%'
```

This would help you in saving some storage space, not sure about the speed.

Comment: The like will result in a fairly inefficient table scan